# how arguments are passed to codeigniter method

Tags: php, codeigniter, get, arguments

I have a method in a codeigniter controller which is sometimes called through the url and sometimes called internally from another method of the controller.  When I call it internally I pass an array of arguments.  Simplified version of method:

(within a controller)

```
function get_details($args='') {

    if (isset($args['first_name'])) 
    {
        $first_name = $args['first_name'];
    } 
    else
    {
        $first_name = $this->uri->segment(3);
    } 

    ... do some other stuff ...

}
```

The method is either called  as:

```
<domain>/<controller>/get_details/abcd/efgh
```

or from another function of the controller as:

```
$this->get_details(array('first_name'=>'abcd', 'last_name'=>'efgh'));
```

I was expecting that when the method was called through the url, isset($args['first_name']) would be false, however it seems that called in this way the argument is there.  I tried printing a couple of things and this is what I got:

```
print_r($args)  ---->   abcd

echo($args['first_name'])  ----> a

echo($args['whatever_index_I_use'])  ----> a
```

It seems like the third parameter of the url is being passed into the method (by codeigniter?), but can't work out why the array indexes seem to be set, all I can think is that php is converting the string to an int, so `$args['whatever_index_I_use'], becomes $args[0]`??

Not sure if this is a codeigniter thing or me missing a subtlety of php.

Much appreciate anyone who can explain what's going on.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any need to pass an array? Could you not just call the method and pass the values through like this: `$this->get_details('abcd', 'efgh');` - you will then have access to them in exactly the same way as when the call is by the browser.

Comment: What happens if you change the isset to [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)?

Comment: is_array($args) returns false, which is good,  I can use it for the test, thanks for that.  However I would still like to understand what is going on with the rest of the code, am I missing something about how php treats strings (for the argument and the index)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is a bug or a expected behavior, but in the [Strings docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#108027) there's a comment that show exactly what are you experiencing. If you use a text and index of the string it will return the first char. To avoid it, check first if the argument is an array or a string:

```
if(is_array($args)) {
    echo($args['first_name']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To complete @SérgioMichels answer, the reason for that is because PHP is expecting an integer as the given index. When you give it a string, PHP will cast the string into an integer, and assuming that the string does not start with a number, type casting will return 0 otherwise, it will return the leading number.

```
$str = 'abcdefghi';
var_dump($str['no_number']); // Outputs: string(1) "a"
var_dump($str['3something']); // Outputs: string(1) "d"
```

Comment: thanks also, didn't realise php would treat a string as an array and force numeric indexes - easy to get caught out by this - hop
efully this can help someone else with the same problem

Answer (score 1):

To specifically answer your question - this will solve your bug:

```
function get_details($args='') 
{
    if (is_array($args))
    {
        $first_name = $args['first_name'];
    } 
    else
    {
        $first_name = $this->uri->segment(3);
    } 
    ... do some other stuff ...
}
```

But you have some issues with your code. Firstly you state that you call the method as

```
<domain>/<controller>/get_details/abcd/efgh
```

but you dont accept the "efgh" variable in your controller. To do this, you need to change the function to

```
function get_details($first, $last)
```

in which case you can now just call the function as

```
$this->get_details('abcd', 'efgh');
```

and now you dont even need to test for arrays etc, which is a better solution IMO.

If you decide to stick with arrays, change:

```
$first_name = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

to

```
$first_name = $args;
```

because by definition - $args IS The 3rd URI segment.